# get count of data from previous 12 months start with sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, pivot

I am having scenario like this : I have table has date field.like

```
id | date     |name |
1  |1/12/2012 |new  |
1  |1/12/2012 |renew  |
1  |1/09/2012 |new  |
1  |1/12/2012 |renew  |
```

i need to get count like |

```
  name |Jan-12| Feb-12 | Mar-12| ....... |Dec-12|
   |new  |0     | 0      | ............... |1     |
   |renew|0     | 0      | ............... |2     |
```

if i give todays date in where condition count need to display for last 12 months monthly wise.and the dates are dynamic if  i enter today date output will be display previous 12 months from sysdate

please give me some solution.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Was it not working?

Comment: @notionquest working partially but the requirement need to get columns dynamically in pivot in condition  ('2015-10', '2015-11', '2015-12', '2016-01', '2016-02',
'2016-03','2016-04','2016-05','2016-06''2016-07','2016-08','2016-09', '2016-10')

Answer (score 3):

You would get the results that you have shown as row (one row for each month) rather than columns.

```
Select to_char(YOUR_DATE, 'YYYY-MM'), count(id)
FROM table_name a
WHERE YOUR_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
GRoup by to_char(YOUR_DATE, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1;
```

Something like below:-

```
2015-10 79
2015-11 223
2015-12 193
2016-01 182
```

**Using PIVOT:-**

```
Select * FROM
(Select to_char(YOUR_DATE, 'YYYY-MM') AS "TDATE"
FROM table_name a
WHERE YOUR_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE) 
PIVOT ( count (TDATE) for (TDATE) IN ('2015-10', '2015-11', '2015-12', '2016-01', '2016-02',
'2016-03','2016-04','2016-05','2016-06''2016-07','2016-08','2016-09', '2016-10'));
```

Please note that the IN clause is mandatory and it needs to be present for column headings.

Answer (score 0):

Add condition on date as, "date between dateadd(mm,-12,@YourDate) and @YourDate"

Comment: SELECT SUM(a.oct_count),SUM(a.sep_count) FROM 
(SELECT 
case DATEPART(month,sr.DocumentDate)
WHEN   10
THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) from Table1 sr1 where DATEPART(month,sr1.DocumentDate) = 10
AND sr.ID = sr1.ID ) END AS oct_count,
case DATEPART(month,sr.DocumentDate)
WHEN   9
THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) from Table1 sr1 where DATEPART(month,sr1.DocumentDate) = 9
AND sr.ID = sr1.ID ) END AS sep_count
from Table1 sr
WHERE sr.DocumentDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()) a

Comment: you can add more conditions on each CASE statment.. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use PIVOT operator.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1)
The PIVOT operator takes data in separate rows, aggregates it and converts it into columns as desired in your case.

Here is the query you can use to pivot your data from rows to columns ..

```
with test_tbl AS
(
select 1 id,  '01/12/2012' i_date, 'new' name from dual
union all
select 1 id,  '01/12/2012' i_date, 'renew' name from dual
union all
select 1 id,  '01/09/2012' i_date, 'new' name from dual
union all
select 1 id,  '01/12/2012' i_date, 'renew' name from dual
)
select * from 
(select name, count(id) as count_id, extract(MONTH FROM to_date(i_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') ) as MONTH  from test_tbl group by name, extract(MONTH FROM to_date(i_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')))
PIVOT ( count(count_id) count_id FOR  MONTH IN (9,12) );
```

-----result ---------------------------

```
NAME  9_COUNT_ID 12_COUNT_ID
----- ---------- -----------
renew          0           1 
new            1           1
```